# Calling C# functions from C++ does create compiled code or not

Tags: c#, c++

If I call C# functions/classes from a C++ project, the C++ code will still be compiled as before? or it will be reversible by a decompiler just like any other C# project?

I am also interested in the performance, if I call a C# function from C++ will it call only the .NET dll assembly function and run fast as a C++ app? or will my entire C++ project run slow like a C# app?

Comment: Are you talking about C++ or C++/CLI? Those are two very different things. How would you call C# code from C++?

Answer (score 1):

C++ and C# are very different, so each one will run in "its own way". C++ will run as a native compiled executable and C# will use the .NET runtime. Each part will run at its normal speed and will be reversibile just as if it were alone, so the C# part will be easier to decompile, while C++ (if the executable is stripped, of course) will be much harder to decompile.

Comment: I would not say "much harder", you just need different tools. Reverse engineering C++ is not that bad.

Comment: With C# decompilers you get almost the same original source code, but if you are talking about assembly language decompilation of C++ then that's a different animal. I don't care about someone dissasembling my C++ code, but I care if someone can get quickly and easily the original source code (like C#)

Comment: That's what I meant - with stripped C++ all you have is a bunch of assembly instructions. Good luck recovering a complex class hierarchy from bare assembly ;)